# Calloc Error: unable to allocate, not enough space

Tags: c, memory-management

This read function will read a input matrix from stdin and store it in mat.
a 5 by 5 matrix input is like the following:

```
5
1
1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Sometime I get the error msg: Unable to allocate space for mat[i], not enough space.
But most of the time the function works with the same input. I am not very good at C, please help.
Thank you in advance.

update: I added: printf("Unable to allocate space for mat[%d]", i);
it says unable to allocate space for mat[4].

I removed the code because I am not supposed to post it online.

Comment: Have you tried some good old `printf` debugging? `printf("%d / Allocating %d\n", i, n * sizeof(int));` before that failing invocation should give you an idea of if there are too many or too large allocations happening.

Comment: Have you done basic debugging? Such as printing out the size of everything you have allocated and checking whether the total is something reasonable and not obviously too much for the system to handle?

Comment: `calloc()` takes two arguments; you're calling it with one... That compiled? If it did, did your compiler complain loudly?

Comment: You are missing `#include`s and each loop you are allocating new `mat`, leacking memory.

Comment: @Shawn New C programmers on SO generally either don't enable or don't heed warnings...

Comment: You should not be allocating any strings, it is not needed for this task. A single fixed char array is sufficient. The way you have it now is memory leaks galore.

Comment: But yeah, I suspect this compiles exactly because the headers are missing and the compiler doesn't know that `calloc` requires two arguments.

Comment: A great example of why you shouldn't cast `malloc()`'s return value. See https://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn up your compiler's warnings (e.g. `-Wall` with gcc or clang).
2. Your compiler will complain that it doesn't know about all of the functions you're using. Add all headers required:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   ```
3. Now that those headers are there, your compiler will complain that:

   ```
   <source>:54:32: error: too few arguments to function 'calloc'
      54 |                 mat[i] = (int*)calloc(n * sizeof(int));
         |                                ^~~~~~
   /usr/include/stdlib.h:542:14: note: declared here
     542 | extern void *calloc (size_t __nmemb, size_t __size)
   ```
4. Fix the `calloc()` invocation to be correct; above, you'll see it should be "number of members, size of each member":

   ```
   mat[i] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
   ```

You had been calling `calloc` with a single argument, so it read another off the stack, and were you unlucky enough, that value on the stack might have been, say, `3735928559`, which might be a bit too much to allocate, especially multiplied with the other value you passed in.

You'll also see you've been calling `strtol()` with an invalid second argument; it should be `char**`, not `char*`. Happily, you can just replace that with an inline `NULL`:

```
n = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, now my compiler is crying.

Comment: You're welcome! Now make it not cry and you'll be happier too.